# Passing a down props to a third component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have three components namely : `NewInvoice`, `InvoicePDF` and `FormDataTable`. The `InvoicePDF` component is supposed to receive props passed in the `NewInvoice` component including the rows in the `FormDataTable` component which is passed as a prop. However, when the `InvoicePDF` component renders, it only passes an empty table with table headers instead of passing the rows added in the `NewInvoice` component through the `FormDataTable` component.  Kindly assist

`FormDataTable` Component.

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const { itemOpen } = props;

  const [showForm, setshowForm] = useState(false)
  // console.log(tableData)

  const tableRows = tableData.map((value, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{value.item}</td>
        <td>{value.amount}</td>
        <td>{value.rate}</td>
        <td>{value.quantity}</td>
        <td>{value.description}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  const addRows = (data) => {
    const totalData = tableData.length;
    data.id = totalData + 1;
    const updatedtableData = [...tableData];
    updatedtableData.push(data);
    setTableData(updatedtableData);

    props.setitemOpen(false);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const json = JSON.stringify(tableRows);
  //   localStorage.setItem("tableRows", json);
  // }, [tableRows]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      
          <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
              <th>Rate</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
        </table>


        {itemOpen && <AddItem show={itemOpen} func={addRows} />}

   
      
    </React.Fragment>
```

`NewInvoice` Component.

```
  const [isInvoicevisible, setisInvoicevisible] = useState(true);
  {isInvoicevisible ? (
<div>
<FormDataTable
   itemOpen={itemOpen}
  setitemOpen={setitemOpen}
  />
</div>
):(
<InvoicePDF
          childComponent={<FormDataTable />}
          //startDate={startDate}
        
          address={address}
          fake={fake_logo}
          name={name}
          vat={Vat}
          subtotal={subtotal}
          invoiceDate={invoiceDate}
          invoiceNo={invoiceNo}
          discount={discount}
        />

)
```

`InvoicePDF` Component.

```
 <div className="new-invoice-client">
              {props.childComponent}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing appropriate props here?
`childComponent={<FormDataTable />}`

Also the correct way to do something you are trying to accomplish is to create a wrapper parent.
Something like
`<FormDataTable {props} />

And the in the wrapper component, get the children from props and render.
`return <div>{props.children}</div>`